# Can I have 2 processes running on a single server, one that listens for requests and one that is in a polling loop on some data storage

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, server

I'm currently looking to build a server that does 2 things:

1. has an API that is callable, it creates, updates, gets and can delete data in a local storage (just as files on the server as its just mocking something for a project)
2. has a loop that just constantly checks the local storage for a property to be true, if its true then it pulls the file and does some changing of values (if it helps its pretending to heat up a room) then put the file back into the data storage with the new value.

I've had a look at using the cluster module that is in Node.js but all the examples seem to be when you want to create several instances of the same server that all do the same thing.

Any ideas?

Many thanks,

Jack

Comment: Yes, this is possible. You don't even need have two processes or use the cluster module - just write non-blocking code.

Comment: Why would you use polling? Assuming the API is the only entry point that updates the local storage, just do the changing of values right from within the API processing.

Comment: 'checks the local storage for a property to be true' - this sounds like you're thinking of localStorage in the browser.  Node doesn't have localStorage.  You can use the file system but really it might be easier to use something like redis for simple persistence.  You could use pub/sub in place of #2.

Comment: @Bergi so eventually the json file will have a scheduling property, so in addition to having something read if its true or false, there will be a process running where it reads start time and end time and changes the boolean value based on that.

Comment: @john_omalley apologies, i meant file system.. the idea is to have it running locally to the server as I still want the processing to happen if say the server lost internet connectivity otherwise the system is in an unknown state

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If polling is your strategy, use a cron library (a la ‘node-cron’ or similar). Schedule a polling procedure and consider issuing a command object (‘Command’ pattern - GOF) if you don’t want to work with events.

If the file system is your chosen path to persistence, use the core fs lib, and prefer async versions of all disk operations.

Cluster is overkill until you need to address scaling issues and load balancing.

See the comments, though they don’t directly answer your question, they are viable alternatives. Remember that node’s event driven architecture is well suited to your use case if you choose to use it that way.